# mechanics of variable scope in c++

Tags: c++

I had a question about scope in c++. My buddy gave me a practice test to help prepare for an upcoming technical exam and I wasn't sure how to answer one question.

I'm given the code snippet

```
int nValue1 = 12, nTotal =0;
nTotal += nValue1;
{
    int nValue1 = 14;
    nTotal += nValue1;
}
nTotal += nValue1;
```

I need a refresher on the mechanics of scope, because I'm not sure which of the following answers is best.

A) When the code goes out of scope, the compiler remembers to restore its value back to 12.

B) When the code goes out of scope, the original nValue1 is used again.

I think the answer is B, is that right?

Comment: This code is wrong because `nValue1` is used before it's declared.

Comment: Um... The question makes no sense to me. What "original `nValue`" is it talking about? I'd understand if the inner variable was also called `nValue`. But it isn't.

Comment: It is obviously a typo, the outer declaration is intended to be `nValue1`, also, based on the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is neither.

There is no "original value", and there is nothing to remember.

They are two separate, independent, variables. Within the inner scope, the symbol `nValue1` refers to one variable. Outside of the inner scope the symbol `nValue1` refers to a different variable.

Even inside the inner scope, the outer scope's `nValue1` can be modified (through a pointer, or some equivalent mechanism). When the inner scope exist, `nValue1` isn't "remembered" to have the same value as it did before the scope, but whatever value was updated, indirectly, while the inner scope was in effect.

Comment: Well the only other possible answer choice is
c) since we change nValue1 inside some braces, the complier knows to push its value on the stack upon hitting the opening brace. Upon hitting the closing brace, the compiler pulls the value back off the stack.

Comment: @ZachEllis: Sorry to hear you got a bad test. "Stack" is an inconvenient term. There's a conceptual data stack, and all local non-static variables are on it, there's a conceptual function call stack, and there probably is a physical stack on your CPU. All the variables in your example are on the conceptual stack. None of them will probably be on the physical stack because any CPU has more than 2 registers.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an **addition to Sam Varshavchiks correct answer**, because of your comment on it. So if you mean, you spare a variable in your case, because you reuse the name, it is not the case. I'll try to illustrate for you, how equivalent code but without reusing the name of a variable in an inner scope (which is also known as "shadowing") would look like:

```
int nValue1 = 12, nTotal =0;
nTotal += nValue1;
{
    int nValue2 = 14;
    nTotal += nValue2;
}
nTotal += nValue1;
```

if you put it into a

```
int main() {
 // place the relevant code snipped here
}
```

and look at the generated assembler code, you will see the same output for both cases:

```
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 12
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 0
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    add     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], eax
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], 14
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
    add     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], eax
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    add     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], eax
    mov     eax, 0
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

You can verify this with the Compiler Explorer:

Your code using `nValue1`: [Your code + assembler](https://godbolt.org/g/80YlDB)

My equivalent using `nValue2`: [My code + assembler](https://godbolt.org/g/jksn2e)